# Backup Azure DNS Settings

Tags: backup, azure, dns-zone

We are using Azure DNS to host many nameservers for our costumer domains that are facing the public internet. I would like to backup these settings in a easy way, in case of disaster or someone accedently delete the dns zone.

Any simple way?

Comment: You are aware that there is both an API as well asa command line interface? Did you bother trying them out? Or would you like a premade solution with cherries on top, pretty please?

Comment: `AXFR` the zone to a private secondary (non-Azure) DNS server that you back up.

Comment: Hey, No, i was just looking for a easy way to make a backup incase of disaster, best thing ive came up with this far is to "export templete"

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is going to be to store your DNS settings in some sort of template (ARM, Terraform, Pulumi etc.) and make your changes via that. You then have a controlled process for making changes, and your template can be version controlled, backed up and so in. In the event of a disaster you can re-deploy the template, but only if you keep it as your source of truth, no manual updates to the zones.